# Updating UI after retrieving device settings

Tags: iphone, swift, asynchronous

I want to do something simple in Swift.  I have to retrieve some setting from a device and then initialize some UI controls with those settings.  It may take a few seconds to complete the retrieval so I don't want the code to continue until after the retrieval (async).

I have read countless posts on many websites including this one and read many tutorials.  None seem to work for me.

Also, in the interest of encapsulation, I want to keep the details within the device object.

When I run the app I see the print from the initializing method before I see the print from the method.

```
// Initializing method

brightnessLevel = 100
device.WhatIsTheBrightnessLevel(level: &brightnessLevel)
print("The brightness level is \(brightnessLevel)")


// method with the data retrieval code

func WhatIsTheBrightnessLevel(level brightness: inout Int) -> CResults
{
var brightness: Int
var characteristic: HMCharacteristic
var name: String
var results: CResults
var timeout: DispatchTime
var timeoutResult: DispatchTimeoutResult



// Refresh the value by querying the lightbulb
name = m_lightBulbName
characteristic = m_brightnessCharacteristic!
brightness = 100
timeout = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(CLightBulb.READ_VALUE_TIMEOUT)
timeoutResult = .success
results = CResults()
results.SetResult(code: CResults.code.success)
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async
  {
  //let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
  dispatchGroup.enter()
  characteristic.readValue(completionHandler:
    { (error) in
      if error != nil
        {
        results.SetResult(code: CResults.code.homeKitError)
        results.SetHomeKitDescription(text: error!.localizedDescription)
        print("Error in reading the brightness level for \(name): \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
       else
          {
          brightness = characteristic.value as! Int
          print("CLightBulb: -->Read the brightness level.  It is \(brightness) at " + Date().description(with: Locale.current))
          }
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    })
    timeoutResult = dispatchGroup.wait(timeout: timeout)
    if (timeoutResult == .timedOut)
      {
      results.SetResult(code: CResults.code.timedOut)
      }
     else
        {
        print("CLightBulb: (After wait) The brightness level is \(brightness) at " + Date().description(with: Locale.current))
        self.m_brightnessLevel = brightness
        }
  }
return(results)
}



Thank you!
```

Comment: Judging from your code, it looks like you're making it way too complicated than it needs to be. What are you calling that's async? Your async function should have a callback (i.e. closure) and then you can change what you need on the main thread (where the UI runs). When you say you don't want the code to continue, then you shouldn't put anything after the async function and put everything you want to execute after the async call in the closure. Also, I don't think you need a DispatchGroup for this.

Comment: Thank you for your time... You are probably right, where do I add the closure?  What I really wanted to do was use make a synchronous thread because "characteristic.readValue" is asynchronous and I want to wait until it's compeletionHandler runs before the main thread continues.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not sure closures are the answer.  The key is that I have to make sure this line "brightness = characteristic.value as! Int" gets executed before I initialize the control.  The method "WhatIsTheBrightnessLevel" is completing before that happens.

Comment: When doing anything async, closure is usually the answer. The reason why WhatIsTheBrightnessLevel is completing is because the call to characteristic.readValue is async. Meaning, your function will flow through even while characteristic.readValue is still working (i.e. executing on a different thread). Like I said in previous comment, if you don't want something to get executed until characteristic.readValue is finished, you need to structure your code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Swift and iOS development... can you show me how to change "WhatIsTheBrightnessLevel" or the call to it (or both) so it uses a closure?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to wrap an async function with your own function, it's generally best to give your wrapper function a completion handler as well. Notice the call to your completion handler. This is where you'd pass the resulting values (i.e. within the closure):

```
func getBrightness(characteristic: HMCharacteristic, completion: @escaping (Int?, Error?) -> Void) {

    characteristic.readValue { (error) in

        //Program flows here second

        if error == nil {
            completion(characteristic.value as? Int, nil)
        } else {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }

    //Program flows here first
}
```

Then when you call your function, you just need to make sure that you're handling the results within the completion handler (i.e. closure):

```
getBrightness(characteristic: characteristic) { (value, error) in

    //Program flows here second

    if error == nil {
        if let value = value {
            print(value)
        }
    } else {
        print("an error occurred: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}

//Program flows here first
```

Always keep in mind that code will flow through before the async function completes. So you have to structure your code so that anything that's depending on the value or error returned, doesn't get executed before completion.

Comment: Thank you very much!  But I still have the problem with "you have to structure your code so that anything that's depending on the value...".  The code in the initialization logically goes like this:  "Get Brightness" then "Assign Value".  How do I structure that so it doesn't get executed before completion?

Comment: All I'm saying, in your case, is that you shouldn't do anything that depends on the characteristic.value until the completion handler is called. For example, if UI is involved, meaning, you want to show the value of characteristic.value somewhere in the UI, you have to wait until the completion handler has been called before showing the results. Sometimes when dealing with UI, it makes sense to show an "activity indicator" on screen and prevent the user from using the UI until the value is available or there's an error. You should google Swift completion handler and you'll find examples.

Comment: "you have to wait until the completion handler has been called..."... exactly :) . will the activity indicator do that?  How do I get the code to wait?